# how to replace or remove or update line(s) in file using jave FIle i/o

Tags: java, file, file-io, collections, java-io

The following is my java class file :

```
Public class subscriberAction {
private Service1 s1 = ServiceFactory.getServiceImpl1();
private Service2 s2 = ServiceFactory.getServiceImpl2();
----
----
----

public Service1 getServiceImpl1Obj(){
    -----
    ----
    return s1.getInstance();
}

public Service2 getServiceImpl2Obj(){
    -----
    ----
    return s2.getInstance();
}
```

}// end of class

I would like to **remove private class variables** and modify the **return statement** like following code by using java code dynamically. if i run programmed java file, **SubscriberAction java** file should modify like this.

```
Public class SubscriberAction {

public Service1 getServiceImpl1Obj(){
    -----
    ----
    return ServiceFactory.getServiceImpl1().getInstance();
}

public Service2 getServiceImpl2Obj(){
    -----
    ----
    return ServiceFactory.getServiceImpl2().getInstance();
}
```

}

Could you please help me how to write the java code?

Comment: Well which bit are you stuck on? The simplest approach would probably be to read the whole file into a `List<String>`, modify the list, then write it out again. Which of those tasks is a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it directly on your file. Here is how you can achieve it:

> 1. Read your original file line by line
> 2. If there is no modification required for the line, copy it to a backup/temp file
> 3. If line change is required, write the updated line to the backup/temp file. If line is not required, don't write it to the backup/temp file.
> 4. Once reading the original and writing to the backup/temp is finished, delete the original file
> 5. Rename the backup/temp as original file

I hope you can write the code for the same!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say use an ArrayList and do something similar to what Juned Ahsan said but without the need for a second file.

1. Read your original file line by line
2. And place it in the ArrayList if that line is not to be changed
3. Change/Replace/Delete

   - If you must change/replace the line, then change/replace it and place it in the ArrayList
   - If you must delete the line...do nothing
4. Once you're done reading in, write to the original file, overwriting what was already in it.

Using this method you can avoid having to use and rename another file and it still can do what you are asking for.